# Can someone explain to me what's going on in this regular expression? (Python)

Tags: python, regex

```
s = "hi mom, *please* send more *money*, luv!"
p = r"\*([^\*]+)\*"

print( "s = '", s, "'", sep = "" )
s = re.sub( p, r"<em>\1</em>", s )
print( "s = '", s, "'", sep = "" )
```

the output is:

```
s = 'hi mom, *please* send more *money*, luv!'

s = 'hi mom, <em>please</em> send more <em>money</em>, luv!'
```

And I just really don't understand what is happening. I think I understand that in 
`p = r"\*([^\*]+)\*"`, the r represents a raw string, and when this r prefix is present, "a character following a backlash is included in the string without change." Okay, so far so good. So the first and last * in p will be escaped, meaning that they will be included in the string. I get that.  I know the parentheses in ( ) are used to match but also to indicate the starts and ends of groups. I also assume that the "1" in `s = re.sub(p , r"<em>\1</em>", s)` has something to do with a group. But...I don't know, it's just not all coming together and I'm really not understanding how we get the second string. Can someone like..walk me through this?

Comment: You really need to concentrate on `[^\*]+` part, this matches any char but not of `*` one or more times, so this matches `please` and `money` for the above string. `\*` at the start and at the end helps to capture the exact string present inside two stars `**`

Comment: u r confused abt s = re.sub( p, r"<em>\1</em>", s ) part?

Comment: @AvinashRaj so it's like..we want to match any character except * one or more times that is within the two * symbols?

Comment: ya, exactly. `\1` refers the captured characters ie please and money.

Comment: in [^ \ *], is the \ escaping the * ? Or are both \ and * both being excluded from what we want to match? Because I read that special characters lose meaning inside sets, so is the \ in this case unnecessary? @AvinashRaj

Comment: ya, exactly you don't need to escape `*` present inside a char class. `\*([^*]+)\*`

Answer (score 0):

`*` is a special character in regular expressions so `r"\*"` is escaping the * for the re engine so that it knows it is looking for a literal `*`

`[^\*]+` means 1 or more characters that are not a literal star

`\1` refers to the capture group (whatever is between the parentheses)

https://www.debuggex.com/r/tety3IA93jSB1iah demonstrates the regex match .. the darker highlight is what matches inside the capture group

Answer (score 0):

```
p = r"\*([^\*]+)\*"
```

This means between two *, match one or more characters that is not (^) a *

> If the first character of the set is '^', all the characters that are
>   not in the set will be matched. For example, [^5] will match any
>   character except '5', and [^^] will match any character except '^'.
>   [Source: Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

```
s = re.sub( p, r"<em>\1</em>", s )
```

Replace the matched string i.e. *please* with <em>Group 1</em>. Group 1 being everything captured between the () ie. please & money. You only have one group in the regular expression, if you had more than one, you would use \2 to get the contents of the 2nd group and so on.